# Postgis installation error

Tags: postgis, installation

I am using fedora machine. I want to install postgis on my system. So this is what I have done

1. Installed Postgresql and supporting packages using YUM.
2. Created directory /sources to put all the necessary packages for postgis.
3. successfully installed geos,libxml & proj using ./config,make,make install.
4. successful in make & make install of postgis.

But when I give "make check" I am getting the following error(I have already started the postgres server):

```
[root@localhost sources]# cd postgis/

[root@localhost postgis]# ls 

postgis-1.5.0SVN  postgis-1.5.0SVN.tar.gz 

[root@localhost postgis]# cd postgis-1.5.0SVN 

[root@localhost postgis-1.5.0SVN]# make check 

make -C liblwgeom 

make[1]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/liblwgeom' 

make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 

make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/liblwgeom' 

make -C postgis 

make[1]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/postgis' 

Makefile.pgxs:17: warning: overriding recipe for target `install' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:92: warning: ignoring old recipe for 
target `install' 

Makefile.pgxs:63: warning: overriding recipe for target `installdirs' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:140: warning: ignoring old recipe for 
target `installdirs' 

Makefile.pgxs:82: warning: overriding recipe for target `uninstall' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:164: warning: ignoring old recipe for 
target `uninstall' 

make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 

make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/postgis' 

make -C liblwgeom/cunit check 

make[1]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/liblwgeom/cunit' 

WARNING: 

configure was unable to find CUnit which is required for unit testing. 
In order to enable unit testing, you must install CUnit and then re-run configure. 

make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/liblwgeom/cunit' 

make -C regress check 

make[1]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress' 

make -C ../postgis REGRESS=1 DESTDIR=/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install install 

make[2]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/postgis' 

Makefile.pgxs:17: warning: overriding recipe for target `install' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:92: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `install' 

Makefile.pgxs:63: warning: overriding recipe for target `installdirs' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:140: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `installdirs' 

Makefile.pgxs:82: warning: overriding recipe for target `uninstall' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:164: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `uninstall' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/mkinstalldirs '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/lib' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  postgis-1.5.so '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/lib/postgis-1.5.so' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./../spatial_ref_sys.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 postgis.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 uninstall_postgis.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 postgis_upgrade_15_minor.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 postgis_upgrade_14_to_15.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 postgis_upgrade_13_to_15.sql '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis-1.5' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  postgis-1.5.so '/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/lib/postgis-1.5.so' 

make[2]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/postgis' 

make -C ../loader REGRESS=1 DESTDIR=/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install install 

make[2]: Entering directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/loader' 

Makefile:108: warning: overriding recipe for target `clean' 
/usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:211: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `clean' 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c pgsql2shp /sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/bin 
/bin/sh /usr/lib/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c shp2pgsql /sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-install/bin 

make[2]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/loader' 
sed 's,$libdir,/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress/00-regress-
install/lib,g' ../postgis/postgis.sql > postgis.sql 

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? 

Creating spatial db postgis_reg 

createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? 

createlang: could not connect to database postgis_reg: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? 

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? 

dropdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? 

Something went wrong (no postgis installed in postgis_reg). 
 For details, check /tmp/pgis_reg_5204/regress_log 

make[1]: *** [check] Error 1 

make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/postgis/postgis-1.5.0SVN/regress' 

make: *** [check] Error 2 

6.Even with the error, i continued to create template_postgis db from postgresql shell: 
 On giving the command: psql template_postgis -U postgres postgis/postgis.sql I am getting the folowing error: 

psql:postgis/postgis.sql:6859: NOTICE:  type "geography" is not yet defined 
DETAIL:  Creating a shell type definition. 
CREATE FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:6865: NOTICE:  argument type geography is only a shell 
CREATE FUNCTION 
CREATE FUNCTION 
CREATE TYPE 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:6893: NOTICE:  type "gidx" is not yet defined 
DETAIL:  Creating a shell type definition. 
CREATE FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:6899: NOTICE:  argument type gidx is only a shell 
CREATE FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7744: NOTICE:  aggregate geomunion(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP AGGREGATE 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7745: NOTICE:  aggregate st_geomunion(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP AGGREGATE 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7746: NOTICE:  aggregate accum_old(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP AGGREGATE 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7747: NOTICE:  aggregate st_accum_old(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP AGGREGATE 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7750: NOTICE:  function box2d_overleft(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7751: NOTICE:  function box2d_overright(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7752: NOTICE:  function box2d_left(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7753: NOTICE:  function box2d_right(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7754: NOTICE:  function box2d_contain(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7755: NOTICE:  function box2d_contained(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7756: NOTICE:  function box2d_overlap(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7757: NOTICE:  function box2d_same(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7758: NOTICE:  function box2d_intersects(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7759: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_overleft(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7760: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_overright(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7761: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_left(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7762: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_right(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7763: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_contain(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7764: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_contained(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7765: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_overlap(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7766: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_same(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7767: NOTICE:  function st_box2d_intersects(box2d,box2d) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7768: NOTICE:  function st_addbbox(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7769: NOTICE:  function st_dropbbox(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7770: NOTICE:  function st_hasbbox(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7771: NOTICE:  function cache_bbox() does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7772: NOTICE:  function st_cache_bbox() does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7773: NOTICE:  function transform_geometry(geometry,text,text,pg_catalog.int4) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7774: NOTICE:  function collector(geometry,geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7775: NOTICE:  function st_collector(geometry,geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7776: NOTICE:  function geom_accum(geometry[],geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7777: NOTICE:  function st_geom_accum(geometry[],geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7778: NOTICE:  function collect_garray(geometry[]) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7779: NOTICE:  function st_collect_garray(geometry[]) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7780: NOTICE:  function geosnoop(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7781: NOTICE:  function jtsnoop(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7782: NOTICE:  function st_noop(geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
psql:postgis/postgis.sql:7783: NOTICE:  function st_max_distance(geometry,geometry) does not exist, skipping 
DROP FUNCTION 
-bash-4.1$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the regression tests failed to connect to the local postgres install, so it wasn't able to install the postgis schema and functions. So later, when it tried to run the tests, it just failed.

Seems it seems you are building from trunk, did you do:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
./make
sudo make install
```

and then to install PostGIS in a db:

```
createdb yourdatabase
createlang plpgsql yourdatabase
psql -d yourdatabase -f postgis.sql
psql -d yourdatabase -f postgis_comments.sql
psql -d yourdatabase -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

That should work - and if it doesn't, you have a bad version of trunk or some pre-requisite is missing.

I would also check that you can connect to postgres using psql from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pre-compiled RPMs from http://yum.pgrpms.org/.

This repository has the latest stable versions of both PostgreSQL and PostGIS.