# "Geometry" Problem while creating Postgis database on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgis-1.5

I am trying to build pgrouting on ubuntu. Therefore, I now firstly try to create a Postgis database on ubuntu.

I am following the instructions on this site:

[Installing PostGIS 1.5 on PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu](http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2010/03/04/installing-postgis-1-5-0-on-postgresql-8-4-on-ubuntu-9-10/)

I have installed postgresql and postgis.

I now try to run the necessary sql queries:
psql -d my_db -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql

However, I got an error as shown in the screenshot below:

http://postimage.org/image/ggk7xg17p/

It looks like there is a problem with the query as 
-it firstly aborts the transactions continuously and 
-then says type "geometry", "box2d", "geometry" cannot be found

I was expecting these variables to occur as a result of this query. Why am I getting such an error while running the query?

Any idea would be more than welcome.

Thanks!

---

I checked the first error I get on this action:

ERROR Could not access the file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory

I have been checking on Google but not so useful yet. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Your screenshot is not showing the first error. That is the one interesting. The rest is often just a result of the first error.

Comment: Stop on the first error by adding `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` to your psql command; [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6864701/327026)

Comment: Hi Nicklas. As you said, I run it again and captured the first error. It now says:                                            postgres@Bekir-Sony:/home/bekirtopaloglu$ psql -d my_routing -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
SET
BEGIN
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql:59: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to check your `GEOS - (Geometry Engine - Open Source)` version. Box Types and Geometries mostly make the problem with old version of GEOS Library...

you can learn your GEOS version from PostGIS with this way :

```
postgres=# select PostGIS_full_version();
postgis_full_version                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGIS="2.0.0alpha4SVN" GEOS="3.3.2-CAPI-1.7.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1,
7 September 2011" GDAL="GDAL 1.8.1, released 2011/07/09" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

in addition to this you can check this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8246/3071)...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I tried the command you suggested, it didn't work so I couldn't check my version. However, I have visited the GEOS web site and installed the latest version. [geos-3.3.3.tar.bz2] - However, I still get the same failure on geometry and box types while running sql queries on my database to make it postgis enabled. Any other idea?

Comment: you can also write this in sql editor area as **SELECT PostGIS_full_version()**, if geos not works, pls try to uninstall and update your ubuntu then install postgres which will compatible with your ubuntu version..