# ST_HasBBOX does not exists

Tags: postgis

I have the lastest PostGIS version. When I query:

`select ST_HasBBOX(the_geom) from table_geom limit 1`

I get this error:
`ERROR:  function st_hasbbox(geometry) does not exist`

Why this function does not exists

Comment: This may of relevance: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/postgis-installation-error - they have it there too.

Comment: The other PostGIS functions works fine, but I get these error with ST_HasBBOX, also with ST_addBBOX and ST_dropBBOX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have PostGIS 2.0.x, try [PostGIS_HasBBox](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/PostGIS_HasBBox.html).

However do you really need this function? The documentation says it should only be used in [exceptional circumstances](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#Exceptional_Functions).